# Measurable functions and $L^+$

Tags: measure-theory

If $f,g$ are two complex valued measurable functions, then does it imply that $\displaystyle \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}\in L^+$? (I am sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: What is $L^+$? Non-negative measurable functions?

Comment: Yes. $L^+$=the space of all measurable functions from $X$ to $[0,\infty]$. Here $X$ is the measure space.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\to \frac{|x|}
{1+|x|}$$is bounded (by $1$).

Answer (score 0):

If $h : X \to \mathbb C$ is measurable and $\phi : \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, it should be routine to show that $\phi \circ h$ is measurable. Use $\phi(z) = \dfrac{|z|}{1+|z|}$ and $h = f-g$.